# FFMPEG reconnect input if error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm finding a way to make ffmpeg reconnect if any error occurered. For my case I restream from hls to rtmp for example

```
ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2000 -i "input" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://output
```

FFMpeg always disconnected every 10 minutes. I searched on google and can't find stable solution for this job.

P.S. OS is linux (Centos 7 64bit)

Thank you,
Akitab